# Error in matplotlib when implementing K-Means algorithm

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to plot the graph using matplotlib which is been imported as plt but getting an error.

## K-Mean Clustering

```
#importing libraries
import NumPy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd

#importing dataset with pandas
dataset = pd.read_csv('Mall_Customers.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [3,4]].values

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1,11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 10, random_state = 0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-d9dfde180017>", line 8, in <module>
    plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'
```

Comment: Change the import to: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0):

A 'has no attribute' error means the function or variable you're trying to access on an object doesn't exist. When you get this error from a library it means you did not read the library api documentations well enough.

matplotlib is the index of multiple apis, you may be looking for the pyplot api of matplotlib as this has a plot function.

See the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html

See the index of matplotlib apis: https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html

Change

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```